# Combining my two python scripts crashes the script (Crashes when combined, uses FortnitePy and my own scripts)

Tags: python

So, I am trying to program a script that uses fortnitepy (a lobby bot script) to load up (into the lobby) but have the user with the python script open to be able to select a command such as selecting a game mode. I want the loading player part and the invite/friend accept part to be there/work and for the exchange code scripts to load(required to get the bot to work). There is no error, it just crashes. Also, another problem is trying to execute these commands:

---

if "Playlist_" in args[0]:
        try:
            await client.user.party.set_playlist(playlist=args[0])

---

Into the python script with a specific argument (Playlist_DADBRO_Squads_12). I will link the fortnite python script and my script.

Fortnite Python Script Link:
https://github.com/KaosDrip/fortnitepy-bot

My code:

````
import os
try:
    import fortnitepy
    from fortnitepy.errors import *
    import BenBotAsync
    import asyncio
    import time as delay
    import datetime
    import json
    import aiohttp
    import time
    import logging
    import functools
    import sys
    import os
    import random
    from colorama import init
    init(autoreset=True)
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print(Fore.RED + f'Error: LTMLoader not configurated. Could not load modules.')
    exit()

def main():
   menu()
def menu():
    print("LTMLoader 1.0 By ThatsFluke")
    #time.sleep(1)


    choice = input("""
1 : Custom Playlist/Matchmaking Settings
2 : Storm King LTM
3 : Storm Surfers
4 : Food Fight
5 : Unvaulted
6 : Solid Gold
7 : Playground (Buggy)""")

    if choice == "1":
        settings()
    elif choice == "2":
        stormking()
    elif choice == "3":
        stormsurfers()
    elif choice=="4":
        foodfight()
    elif choice=="5":
        unvaulted()
    elif choice=="6":
        solidgold()
    elif choice=="6":
        playground()
    else:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        print(Fore.RED + f'Error: Incorrect Selection.')
        print(Fore.RED + f'Please try again.')
        time.sleep(1)
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
        menu()

def settings():
    pass
def stormking():
    pass
    #input dadbro playlist loader here
def stormsurfers():
    pass
def foodfight():
    pass
def unvaulted():
    pass
def solidgold():
    pass
def playground():
    pass    


main()```
````

Thanks for having a look at my bad code haha

Comment: Add the error in the question.

Comment: @Neeraj it just crashes. There is no error. I just need help combining the code. Thanks!